# Excel Macro sending through Thunderbird

Tags: vba, excel, thunderbird

I was wondering if anyone knew how to build a macro in excel to send the spreadsheet through Thunderbird.

Comment: [so] is for specific, answerable questions. Your posting here is not actually a question. If we distil it a little we get _'Does somebody know...?'_, to which the possible answers are _'yes'_, or _'no'_. Please be a little more precise. See [ask].

Comment: I understood I found the solution given very good, It helped me a lot...

Answer (score 2):

Example

```
Option Explicit
Sub Thunderbird()
    Dim sCmd As String      '// Prepare Thunderbird
    Dim sTo As String       '// Recipient
    Dim sSubject As String  '// Subject
    Dim sBody As String     '// Email body

    sTo = "Test@Email.com"
    sSubject = "Subject"
    sBody = "body text"

    sCmd = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird" '// or
    'sCmd = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird" '// Path
    sCmd = sCmd & " -compose " & Chr$(34) & "mailto:" & sTo & "?" '// Chr$(34)=double quote
    sCmd = sCmd & "subject=" & Chr$(34) & sSubject & Chr$(34)
    sCmd = sCmd & sBody

    Call Shell(sCmd, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: This solution worked well in my version also. @Omar