# How can I automatically send email from Thunderbird with Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, thunderbird

What I want to do is send an email from a Thunderbird account automatically. The user shouldn't even have to hit the Send button of the email.

I've tried using CDO, but the problem with it is that you have to input the username and password of the account you are sending from. This macro will be used from several different accounts, so inputting each username and password isn't feasible. I could use CDO if there was someway of retrieving the username, password, and smtp server from Thunderbird, but I feel like the code I already have should be able to accomplish this without CDO (hopefully).

Here is really the only code I see (and it's everywhere) in regards to accomplishing this.

```
Sub Thunderbird()

Dim thund As String      
Dim email As String 
Dim cc As String
Dim bcc As String 
Dim subj As String  
Dim body As String     

email = "email@test.com"
cc = "cc@test.com"
bcc = "bcc@test.com"
subj = "Subject"
body = "body text"

thund = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" 
thund = thund & " -compose " & Chr$(34) & "mailto:" & email & "?"
thund = thund & "cc=" & Chr$(34) & cc & "?"
thund = thund & "bcc=" & Chr$(34) & bcc & "?"
thund = thund & "subject=" & Chr$(34) & subj & Chr$(34)
thund = thund & "body=" & Chr$(34) & body

Call Shell(thund, vbNormalFocus)
SendKeys "^+{ENTER}", True

End Sub
```

As of right now, the fields `cc`, `bcc`, `subj`, and `body` are all recognized correctly. The problem is they all get added to the end of the first field. For instance, with the way the code is right now, `cc` will get put in the cc field, but `bcc`, `subj`, and `body` all get appended to `cc` in the cc field of Thunderbird.

If I comment `cc` out, then `bcc` is put in the correct field, but `subj` and `body` get appended to `bcc` in the bcc field of Thunderbird.

If I comment `cc` and `bcc` out, then `subj` gets put in the correct field, but `body` gets appended to `subj` in the subject field of Thunderbird.

So basically I need to add the correct code at the end of each of these lines. I've tried both `"?"` and `Chr$(34)` to no avail.

Lastly, `SendKeys "^+{ENTER}", True` isn't working at all. This might be because of all the parameters not being put in the correct field of Thunderbird, but not sure since I can't get that working. Email from Thunderbird displays, but this code isn't sending the email like it's supposed to.

**SOLUTION** (as provided by @zedfoxus)

```
Sub Thunderbird()

Dim thund As String      
Dim email As String 
Dim cc As String
Dim bcc As String 
Dim subj As String  
Dim body As String     

email = "email@test.com"
cc = "cc@test.com"
bcc = "bcc@test.com"
subj = "Subject"
body = "body text"

thund = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" & _
        " -compose " & """" & _
        "to='" & email & "'," & _
        "cc='" & cc & "'," & _
        "bcc='" & bcc & "'," & _
        "subject='" & subj & "'," & _
        "body='" & body & "'" & """"

Call Shell(thund, vbNormalFocus)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
SendKeys "^{ENTER}", True

End Sub
```

Comment: [Excel Macro sending through Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283948/excel-macro-sending-through-thunderbird/31284639#31284639)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close. Try this:

```
Public Sub SendEmail()
    Dim thund As String
    Dim email As String
    Dim cc As String
    Dim bcc As String
    Dim subj As String
    Dim body As String

    email = "test@test.com"
    cc = "test@test.com"
    bcc = "test@test.com"
    subj = "Testing"
    body = "Testing"

    thund = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe " & _
            "-compose " & """" & _
            "to='" & email & "'," & _
            "cc='" & cc & "'," & _
            "bcc='" & bcc & "'," & _
            "subject='" & subj & "'," & _
            "body='" & body & "'" & """"

    Call Shell(thund, vbNormalFocus)
    SendKeys "^+{ENTER}", True

End Sub
```

Notice the example from http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_(Thunderbird).

> thunderbird -compose "to='john@example.com,kathy@example.com',cc='britney@example.com',subject='dinner',body='How about dinner tonight?',attachment='C:\temp\info.doc,C:\temp\food.doc'"

The example indicates that after `-compose` we should use type our information in double-quotes. Each parameter is separated by comma. Nomenclature is `parameter='value[,value]' [,parameter='value[,value]]...`.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the SendKeys bit still doesn't work. The email displays correctly, but SendKeys doesn't send the email. It actually just minimizes the window.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have? What version of Excel do you have? I have Office 365 ProPlus and SendKeys are working perfectly with Thunderbird on Windows 7.

Comment: Try `Application.SendKeys "%fl", True` instead of `SendKeys "^+{ENTER}", True`. If that doesn't work, try `SendKeys "^+~", True`

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1 on Office 2010. After messing around with the 2 options you provided, plus the original, I found out `SendKeys` was sending the key before the window was displayed. I added this before all 3 options and it worked `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))`. Right now though, the emails aren't being sent. They sit in the Outbox folder of Thunderbird. Even with Thunderbird open, this still occurs. I have to go to the Outbox folder and maually send them. Any idea why? I don't see any simple fixes online.

Comment: Try sending `SendKeys "^~", True` or `SendKeys "^{ENTER}", True` or `SendKeys "%fd", True`. They all are CTRL+ENTER - that means Send Now. CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER sends the email later and that's what you are doing by sending `^` (CTRL), `+` (SHIFT) + `{ENTER}`

Comment: Ah. Thank you! I wasn't aware I was simply sending the wrong key combo. I'll update my thread to show the full solution. FYI, in your code `"-compose "` needs to be `" -compose "`. Needs a space before `-compose`, at least it does for me in order to work. Thanks again!

Comment: Notice the line prior to `"-compose "`. That line has a space at the end and therefore I don't need a space before `-compose`. The way I have written that piece of code is my own guideline (sort of) where `"-compose "`, `"to="`, `"cc="` line up to my liking

Comment: My apologies. I completely overlooked that. I agree with you. That way is better.